# Helm simple for loop

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I can not find a way to just iterate over a simple range, 10 -> 20 using helm templating.

```
{{range 10 until 20 }}
    - port: {{ . }}
      targetPort: {{ . }}
      protocol: TCP
      name: brick-{{ . }}
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Helm uses the standard Go [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) system for rendering templates, plus (most of) the [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) extension library, plus a couple more things.  In particular, Sprig includes [`until` and `untilStep`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/integer_slice.html) functions to generate lists of numbers, which you can then `range` over.  So you should be able to:

```
{{- range untilStep 10 20 1 }}
    - port: {{ . }}
      ...
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks to the quick response I still have hair. Much appreciated.

Comment: what about from "a" to "z" . Does untilStep wil work ? or is there ascii function can be applied ?

Comment: PS. this can only get numbers from 10 to 19, just like range in Python.